Setup Databricks Autoloader Event Grid Subscription with No Expiry on TTL
I intend to use Autoloader in file notification mode. I want to control the naming of the event grid subscription and storage queues, so I am using the module recommended in the official docs to achieve this.
The module is com.databricks.sql.CloudFilesAzureResourceManager and how to use it is detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/cloud-object-storage/auto-loader/file-notification-mode#scala
The issue is the TTL (time to live) for events forwarded to the storage queue is 7 days. I want to disable this expiry.
Being new to Scala, Im struggling to find any information about this module beyond the example in the docs. Has it got the capability to set the delivery TTL on the event grid subcscription?
Where does one find the documentation for such a module?
I have a workarounnd using a separate event grid management module to set the TTL after the event grid subscription has been created, but seems like something I'd expect the CloudFilesAzureResourceManager to be able to do..

TTL is something you need to configure from the resource side. No option for it with auto loader
